# Is there particular reason to use に　or と　before or after だけ　in JLPT n5 level sentences?

Tags: particles, jlpt

According to JLPT Study Guide written by Clayton McKnight, one form for だけ　meaning only is Noun+と・に＋だけ＋に・と・が・は・を・で but give no examples of using に・と　before だけ。Is there any reason to prefer in appropriate sentences to put に・と　before だけ　rather after だけ？

Comment: Can you quote the excerpt from the guide to have more context please?

Comment: Is this what you are asking? [にだけ vs だけに　－　Difference in meaning?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61253/43676)

Comment: Yes but also とだけ