# What does にだけにはなるか (vulgar text warning/nsfw) mean?

Tags: verbs, particle-に, particle-だけ

[image]

I am stumbled on the second to left of this sentence.

The character mentioned his revenge failed,  and in the last line he mentions he at least attempted to sleep with a girl. The character is a delinquent who has recently disciplined by the student council over his lecherous behaviors with women. He failed to get back at the student council, but I assume he kept wanting to keep being a delinquent

アイツの言いなりに is "That person's yes man" って may hide an て思う but I don't see what verb in the middle with the だけ use?

What exactly is にだけに?

Answer (score 1):

I think those four lines form one single sentence. Anyway, the underlying expression is 言いなりになる, the combination of noun 言いなり + particle に + verb なる, and other particles (だけ, は and か) are added to it in the given sentence. In fact, にだけに(は) is ungrammatical. The order of three particles attached to 言いなり can be either だけには or にだけは with little change in meaning, but never appears に twice. The character or the author was probably confused about those two possible word orders and mistakenly mixed them.

ps

あいつの言いなりになる means “to become his or her yes-man/puppet”. The particle か indicates here the emphasized determination not to do something “I would never do (something)”, similar to the expression ものか/もんか. The particleは attached to 言いなりに makes contrast; implicitly makes comparison among あいつの言いなりになる and all the other possible situations, and だけ “only” clarify that it’s the last thing he would do.

Comment: I'm slight confused on what hes' trying to say then? What kind of nuance does だけには or にだけは add here (Which have difference nuances here?). The verb here is はなる + か?
"To remove myself as that man yes man"?

Comment: In the sentence, the only verb is なる; は and か are particles. I’ve just added to my answer some explanations about its meaning.

Comment: There have already been good article aboutだけに vs にだけ [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/61253). They are interchangeable (including your case), except for some exceptional constructions.