# じゃな + Noun grammar

Tags: grammar, nouns

I currently playing a game and during the dialog a character says

> そんなワケない**じゃな**イカ!　イカだけに!

What grammar concept is happening with じゃな + noun portion?  Is it really just だな + noun?

My best guess in translating is that they are saying

> That sort of thing is understandable, it's a squid! Given that it is a squid!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This そんなワケないじゃなイカ is "No way!" or "Nonsense!", but said with a pun.

The sentence is the same as そんなワケないじゃないか, which is a double-negative rhetorical question that effectively means the same thing as the single negative そんなワケない. (For this じゃないか, see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1485/5010).) Here, イカ is in katakana because it's a pun on イカ ("squid"). If you see "だけに" used like this, it indicates the associated sentence is intended to be a pun. See: [How do jokes with "だけに" work?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17389/5010)

Comment: So is the a more direct translation: そんなわけないじゃない! -> There is no way that's a thing! Right?. Also follow up question, is the イカだけに just a hint that this is a pun or does it also carry the "Seeing as it's a squid" part too